# Adding SSL To My Django App Running In Daemon Mode With Mod_WSGI

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have done some research and cannot find a solution that works for me...

My current `apache2.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080>

    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    ServerAdmin admin@website.com
    DocumentRoot /home/USER/web/website.com/djagno_project/app/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/web/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/USER/web/website.com/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/USER/web/website.com/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup USER USER
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/USER/web/website.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/USER/web/website.com/django_project/app:/home/USER/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/USER/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/USER/tmp
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/USER/web/website.com/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid USER USER
        RGroups www-data
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID USER USER
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/USER/conf/web/apache2.website.com.conf*

    Alias /static /home/USER/web/website.com/django_project/app/static
    <Directory /home/USER/web/website.com/django_project/app/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/USER/web/website.com/django_project/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/USER/web/website.com/django_project/app/>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes
    </Directory>

    LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so"

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/USER/web/website.com/django_project/project/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess www.website.com socket-user=USER group=USER processes=2 threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup www.website.com
    WSGIApplicationGroup USER

    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/USER/conf/web/ssl.website.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/USER/conf/web/ssl.website.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/USER/conf/web/ssl.website.com.crt

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com$1 [R=permanent,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonHome "/usr/local/.virtualenvs/PROJECT"
```

**Everything was working fine before I started to use SSL**

Before I added SSL, my static files were being loaded fine and everything was working a it had when I was developing my site on my localhost. My research had brought me to the adding of the `SSLEngine` code as well as the `RewriteCond` code (which I found was very beneficial for stopping people from removing the 's' from `https` once the site had loaded.

Comment: What kind of problems do you get ? Try opening the "dev tools" (F12) and see the errors you're getting. Also look at the generated html source code ... maybe django produces wrong URLs(either full static ULRs pointing to the wrong domain or only wrong scheme).

Comment: I have taken SSL support off of my website for now to combat this issue while I try to figure it out, so I cannot go back and check the dev tools right now... But I am thinking it must somehow be the static URL as you mentioned, but I will update my question with my django settings for the static urls

Comment: I would try to make "the things" to produce paths/URLs without the domain part ... but I don't know much about django, so I don't know how or how difficult it is to make it possible :).

Comment: Unrelated but instead of ``WSGIApplicationGroup USER`` use ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`` if you only have the one WSGI application. Some Python packages will not work in Python sub interpreters and that change forces the use of the main interpreter so they do.